# Find and UPDATE value in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello i need find my target row in database (phpmyadmin) and update 1 column in that row.

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE '%{$username}%'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $db_exp = $result['0']['expdate'];
```

i find my target with this code but i need update that i can show column now

Comment: You need to use `UPDATE` to do that

Comment: How is this question related to phpMyAdmin or cPanel?

Comment: php i need update col

Comment: But what do you need to update?? I just see a select query, thats all, maybe try yourself to make a update query and come than back agian

Comment: i need update this col : `expdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE users SET expdate = :newValue WHERE user LIKE :userName
```